# Dividing a row vector data frame by a scalar data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm somewhat new to python and pandas so my apologies if this is a rather basic question.  I have a data frame that consists of a single row vector and another data frame that is a scalar.  When I divide the row vector by the scalar I get NaN.  I've tried using dataframe.div and dataframe/dataframe and neither works.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
mContrib
   AST L/S LCG  AST TRP LCG  AST Jenn LCG  AST MFS LCG
0     0.630327      0.62696      0.570262     0.224609

pcov
          0
0  0.702084

mContrib.div(pcov)
    0  AST Jenn LCG  AST L/S LCG  AST MFS LCG  AST TRP LCG
0 NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN

mContrib/(pcov)
    0  AST Jenn LCG  AST L/S LCG  AST MFS LCG  AST TRP LCG
0 NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `mContrib/(pcov)[0][0]` or `mContrib/(pcov).iloc[0, 0]`.

Comment: mContrib/pcov[0][0] and mContrib/pcov.iloc[0,0] both worked great!  Thanks!